# Need to add From array inside Form array in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Am trying to add dynamic fields in form formgroup where i need to add a formarray inside the from array with in that form group, I have tried but am geeting the following error

*error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:6:16 caused by: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined*

please help me to resolve this issue thanks in advance

here is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jwgcc8CHlAAxqn0CVTZL?p=preview)

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormArray, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public formGroupz: FormGroup;
  constructor(private frmbldr: FormBuilder) { }
  private fieldIdentifier: any;
  items: any[] = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    //Called after the constructor, initializing input properties, and the first call to ngOnChanges.
    //Add 'implements OnInit' to the class.
    this.formGroupz = this.frmbldr.group({
      main:this.frmbldr.array([this.initRules()])
    })
  }
  initRules(){
      return this.frmbldr.group({
      ifgroup: this.frmbldr.array([]),
      truegrp: this.frmbldr.array([]),
      falsegrp: this.frmbldr.array([])
    })
  }
  ifFields() {
    debugger
    return this.frmbldr.group({
      conditionfields: ['']
    })
  }
  initextraField() {
    debugger
    if (this.fieldIdentifier == "true") {
      return this.frmbldr.group({
        truefields: ['']
      })
    }
    else if (this.fieldIdentifier == "false") {
      return this.frmbldr.group({
        falsefields: ['']
      })
    }
  }
  addiffields() {
    debugger
    this.fieldIdentifier = "if";
    const control = <FormArray>this.formGroupz.controls['main']['controls']['ifgroup'];
    const addrCtrl = this.ifFields();
    control.push(addrCtrl);
  }
  addtruefields() {
    debugger
    this.fieldIdentifier = "true";
    const control = <FormArray>this.formGroupz.controls['truegrp'];
    const addrCtrl = this.initextraField();
    control.push(addrCtrl);
  }
  addfalsefields() {
    this.fieldIdentifier = "false";
    const control = <FormArray>this.formGroupz.controls['falsegrp'];
    const addrCtrl = this.initextraField();
    control.push(addrCtrl);
  }
}
```

**Component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroupz">
    <div class="tab-pane">
        <!--<button (click)="addiffields()">addIf</button>-->
        <div class="panel panel-default m-b-10 m-t-0">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 5px 8px;background-color: #e1f5fe;">
                <span>if</span>
                <span (click)="addiffields()" class="material-icons pull-right icon-panel">add_circle</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body p-t-0 p-b-0" formArrayName="main">
                <div *ngFor="let maingroup of formGroupz.controls.main.controls; let i =index">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                        <div *ngFor="let ifgroup of formGroupz.controls.ifgroup.controls; let i =index">
                            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                                <input type="text" formControlName="conditionfields">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default m-b-10 m-t-0">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 5px 8px;background-color: #e1f5fe;">
                <span>True</span>
                <span (click)="addtruefields()" class="material-icons pull-right icon-panel">add_circle</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body p-t-0 p-b-0" formArrayName="main">
                <div *ngFor="let maingroup of formGroupz.controls.main.controls; let i =index">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                        <div *ngFor="let trgrp of formGroupz.controls.truegrp.controls; let i =index">
                            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                                <input type="text" formControlName="conditionfields">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default m-b-10 m-t-0">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 5px 8px;background-color: #e1f5fe;">
                <span>false</span>
                <span (click)="addfalsefields()" class="material-icons pull-right icon-panel">add_circle</span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body p-t-0 p-b-0" formArrayName="main">
                <div *ngFor="let maingroup of formGroupz.controls.main.controls; let i =index">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                        <div *ngFor="let flgrp of formGroupz.controls.falsegrp.controls; let i =index">
                            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                                <input type="text" formControlName="falsefields">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{formGroupz.value | json}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where did you call function `initRules`?

Comment: @Pengyy now check it I have updated the code

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because your current structure is like below:

```
formGroupz(FormGroup)
    |----main(FormArray)               <------- mention here main is FormArray
           |----ifgroup(FormArray)
           |----truegrp(FormArray)
           |----falsegrp(FormArray)
```

If you want to access sub formArray `ifgroup` and same for `truegrp` and `falsegrp`, you can achieve it by below syntax with formArray index(same syntax for template but without `this`):

```
this.formGroupz.get('main').controls[0].get('ifgroup')
// or
this.formGroupz.controls.main.controls[0].controls.ifgroup
```

Also make sure your template are pairing to your form structure.

refer **[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/aVKrOhNsyINlzqVSKuJw?p=preview)**(fixed template form structure).

---

BTW, if you don't need the first layer formArray, here is a simpler **[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/gKBSWVFgernNuxoOWH4k?p=preview)** which changed `main` to `formGroup`.

Comment: am getting Cannot find control with path error, your plunkr is working correctly when i apply it to my code its not am getting error

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav you have to follow the structure defined in your component. And access sub formArray step by step. BTW, if my answer solved your problem, please consider accept it.